# SQL Server: skip decimals after executing query

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to get the top users who doesn't pay their bills in time

```
Select ddo.CODE,
  Round(100.0 * Count(fpp.ID) / (Select Count(fpp2.ID)
  From date_check fpp2 Inner Join DIM_PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dppc2
      On fpp2.CHARACTERISTICS_ID = dppc2.ID
  Where dppc2.ONTIME_FLAG = 'N'), 0) As UPPERCENTAGE
From date_check fpp
  Inner Join DIM_PAY_CHARACTERISTICS dppc On fpp.CHARACTERISTICS_ID = dppc.ID
  Inner Join DIM_DATA_OWNER ddo On fpp.DATA_OWNER_ID = ddo.ID
Where dppc.ONTIME_FLAG = 'N'
Group By ddo.CODE
Order By Count(fpp.ID) Desc
```

I get following results:

> Vansteenberge-Jan 50.000000000
>
> Kempeneers-Jim   25.0000000000
>
> Lemaire-Sam  25.000000000000

I want to skip the 0000000 after the dot. So 50, 25 and 25 has to be the result. What do I need to change? I thought about replacing 100.0 by 100 in my percentage calculation but then it doesn't round my query correct. What do I need to do?

Comment: `select convert(decimal(10, 0), Round(100.0 *  6/4, 0)) As UPPERCENTAGE`

Comment: Works, put it as answer and I mark it :)